# unix shell script : How can I get just the number from the variable contain numbers and characters?

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, unixodbc

How can I get just the number from the variable contain numbers and characters??

for example:
card=3Hearts

How can I get just the number (3) from the variable $card ?

Answer (score 0):

`echo 3Hart | tr -d "[[a-zA-Z]]"`

Answer (score 0):

It's slight overkill for this particular problem, but `expr` is very powerful this sort of matching problem:

```
expr $card : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)'
```

and if you want to get that into another variable:

```
t=`expr $card : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)'`
```

The `expr` command can do a variety of things, but this colon operator – which matches the first argument against a regular expression – has lots of uses.

Comment: It is not clear what Ako wants after `card="a1b2c3"`
`expr $card : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)` will return 1, perhaps Ako wants `123`. Please use t=$(..) for nesting commands in the future.